# VBA regexp to check special symbols

Tags: regex, vba, testing

I have tried to use what I've learnt in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops),
and now I want to compose a RegExp which checks whether a string contains digits and commas. For example, "1,2,55,2" should be ok, whereas "a,2,55,2" or "1.2,55,2" should fail test. My code:

```
Private Function testRegExp(str, pattern) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    If pattern <> "" Then
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .pattern = pattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(str) Then
            testRegExp = True
        Else
            testRegExp = False
        End If
    Else
        testRegExp = True
    End If
End Function

Public Sub foo()
    MsgBox testRegExp("2.d", "[0-9]+")
End Sub
```

MsgBox yields true instead of false. What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches a partial string, it matches a digit in all `55,2`, `a,2,55,2`, `1.2,55,2` input strings.

Use anchors `^` and `$` to enforce a *full string match* and add a comma to the character class as you say you want to match strings that only contain digits and commas:

```
MsgBox testRegExp("2.d", "^[0-9,]*$")
                          ^    ^  ^
```

I also suggest using `*` quantifier to match *0 or more occurrences*, rather than `+` (*1 or more occurrences*), but it is something you need to decide for yourself (whether you want to allow an empty string match or not).

Here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF6rF9/1). Note it is for PCRE regex flavor, but this regex will perform similarly in VBA.

Yes, as [@Chaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3771147/chaz) suggests, *if you do not need to match the string/line itself*, the alternative is to match an inverse character class:

```
MsgBox testRegExp("2.d", "[^0-9,]")
```

This way, the [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^0-9,]` will match any character but a comma / digit, invalidating the string.  If the result is `True`, it will mean the string contains some characters other than digits and a comma.

Comment: Or, alternatively, use the inverse of a partial match of the occurrence of any character that is not a digit or comma, i.e: [^0-9,]. You'll need to reverse the return value.

Comment: @Chaz: I assumed OP needs to match the strings, but looking at the code, it is clear OP is interested in Match/No match result.

Comment: `[0-9,]*$` can match at the end of the strng. Thus, it will find a match in `dew%#$%#9,` string. You wrote you need to match strings that only contain digits and commas, right? `^[0-9,]*$` is the right regex for it. If you want to just check if a string has anything else, just check with `[^0-9,]`. Or else, precise what  you need to obtain given some specific string.

Comment: It was all about ^ and $, as you explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the limited built in pattern matching for that:

```
function isOk(str) As boolean
    for i = 1 To len(str)
        if Mid$(str, i, 1) Like "[!0-9,]" then exit function
    next
    g = True and Len(str) > 0
end function
```